# How to configure a custom field with auto increment value?

Tags: jira

I have a jira workflow which going in loop, if certain transition execute as "solution failed".my problem is I need to count how many times a ticket got "solution failed".is there anyway I can achieve this?.and also this count need to be view in a ticket as well.

Initially I created a custom field and attached to relevant screens in the workflow.then after that how can I count the times that the ticket going through a certain transition.this field should be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Script Runner you may create a scripted field that will just count relevant `changeItems`. This is example to count how many times an issue has been put into `Closed` status.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def items = ComponentAccessor.changeHistoryManager.getAllChangeItems(issue).findAll{it.field=="status" && it.getTos().iterator().next().value=="Closed"}
items.size().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

JIRA itself won't be able to do what you are planning. You'll have to use an addon, probably ScriptRunner or JJupin. You can use the last free release of ScriptRunner to avoid the commercial license.

More info here https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/266510/script-to-increment-value-of-custom-field-in-post-validation-condition